# Deleting variable number of leading characters from a variable-length string

Tags: excel, vba

If I am having G4ED7883666 and I want the output to be 7883666
and I have to apply this on a range of cells and they are not the same length and the only common thing is that I have to delete anything before the number that lies before the alphabet?

Comment: That's going to be difficult for strings of unknown length where you have unknown numbers lengths embedded at the start. You can't check for `aNN` where `a` is a letter and `N` is a number if you can have *G4ED7883666* / *G44D79999* / *G4A56B123456* etc. Can you say that the first x number of characters will be alphanumeric and the rest just numeric?

Answer (score 3):

This formula finds the last number in a string, that is, all digits to the right of the last alpha character in the string.

```
  =RIGHT(A1,MATCH(99,IFERROR(1*MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW($1:$25),1),99),0)-1)
```

Note that this is an array formula and must be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> keyboard combination.

#### How the formula works

Let's assume that the target string is fairly simple: **"G4E78"**

Working outward from the middle of the formula, the first thing to do is create an array with the elements 1 through 25. (Although this might seem to limit the formula to strings with no more than 25 characters, it actually places a limit of 25 digits on the size of the number that may be extracted by the formula.

```
ROW($1:$25) = {1;2;3;4;5;6;7; etc.}
```

Subtracting from this array the value of (1 + the length of the target string) produces a new array, the elements of which count down from the length of string. The first five elements will correspond to the position of the characters of the string - in reverse order!

```
LEN(A1)+1-ROW($1:$25) = {5;4;3;2;1;0;-1;-2;-3;-4; etc.}
```

The MID function then creates a new array that reverses the order of the characters of the string.

For example, the first element of the new array is the result of MID(A1, 5, 1), the second of MID(A1, 4, 1) and so on. The #VALUE! errors reflect the fact that MID cannot evaluate 0 or negative values as the position of a string, e.g., MID(A1,0,1) = #VALUE!.

```
MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW($1:$25),1) = {"8";"7";"E";"4";"G";#VALUE!;#VALUE!; etc.}
```

Multiplying the elements of the array by 1 turns the character elements of that array to #VALUE! errors as well.

```
=1*MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW($1:$25),1) = {"8";"7";#VALUE!;"4";#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!; etc.}
```

And the IFERROR function turns the #VALUES into 99, which is just an arbitrary number greater than the value of a single digit.

```
IFERROR(1*MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW($1:$25),1),99) = {8;7;99;4;99;99;99; etc.}
```

Matching on the 99 gives the position of the first non-digit character counting from the right end of the string. In this case, "E" is the first non-digit in the reversed string "87E4G", at position 3. This is equivalent to saying that the number we are looking for at the end of the string, plus the "E", is 3 characters long.

```
MATCH(99,IFERROR(1*MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW($1:$25),1),99),0) = 3
```

So, for the final step, we take 3 - 1 (for the "E) characters from the right of string.

```
RIGHT(A1,MATCH(99,IFERROR(1*MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW($1:$25),1),99),0)-1) = "78"
```

Answer (score 2):

One more submission for you to consider. This VBA function will get the right most digits before the first non-numeric character

```
Public Function GetRightNumbers(str As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Len(str) To 0 Step -1
        If Not IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    GetRightNumbers = Mid(str, i + 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write some VBA to format the data (just starting at the end and working back until you hit a non-number.)

Or you could (if you're happy to get an addin like [Excelicious](http://excelicious.wordpress.com/code-samples/vba/regex-functions/)) then you can use regular expressions to format the text via a formula.  An expression like `[0-9]+$` would return all the numbers at the end of a string IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: This uses the regex pattern in James Snell's answer, so please upvote his answer if you find this useful.

Your best bet is to use a regular expression. You need to set a reference to VBScript Regular Expressions for this to work. **Tools --> References...**
[image]

Now you can use regex in your VBA.

This will find the numbers at the end of each cell. I am placing the result next to the original so that you can verify it is working the way you want. You can modify it to replace the cell as soon as you feel comfortable with it. The code works regardless of the length of the string you are evaluating, and will skip the cell if it doesn't find a match.

```
Sub GetTrailingNumbers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim result As Object, results As Object
    Dim regEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' range is hard-coded here, but you can define
    ' it programatically based on the shape of your data
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A3")

    ' pattern from James Snell's answer
    regEx.Pattern = "[0-9]+$"

    For Each cell In rng
        If regEx.Test(cell.Value) Then
            Set results = regEx.Execute(cell.Value)
            For Each result In results
                cell.Offset(, 1).Value = result.Value
            Next result
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Takes the first 4 digits from the right of num:

```
num1=Right(num,4)
```

Takes the first 5 digits from the left of num:

```
num1=Left(num,5)
```

First takes the first ten digits from the left then takes the first four digits from the right:

```
num1=Right(Left(num, 10),4)
```

In your case:

```
num=G4ED7883666

num1=Right(num,7)
```

Comment: I don't understand that answer. Does it word for multi length values?

Comment: That might work for the example but not for variable number of letters/numbers